# ¿Porqué no me funciona la etiqueta <audio> con autoplay en una apk?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, apk

sé que esta etiqueta con autoplay no debería de funcionar en la mayoria de navegadores, pero mi problema es que estoy desarrollando una apk de una llamada con html, la cual va a incluir un tono de llamada el cual sería el audio. Mi problema se encuentra en que cuando lo paso a APK, no lo reproduce, ni aun con el autoplay.

Dejo el código por aqui:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio'); audio.addEventListener("loadstart", showVideo, false);
    function showVideo(e) {
      audio.play();
    }
  </script>

</head>

<div>
  <audio id="audio" src="assets/audio/tono.mp3">
  </audio>
</div>

<body id="llamada-fondo">
  <div id="title" class="d-flex text-center justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <img src="assets/img/circular.png" style="height: 10%; width: 30%;"><br>
  </div>
  <p style="color: white; text-align: center;">+34 6445467865</p>
  <div id="aceptar">
    <img id="aceptarllamada" src="assets/img/aceptar.png">
    <img id="denegarllamada" src="assets/img/denegar.png">
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: La mayoría de navegadores bloquean las reproducciones automáticas de archivos multimediales que contengan audio. Dicho esto, usando `audio.play()` en  javascript debería solucionarlo, prueba a poner un script al final del body que contenga solo esta línea: `var audio=document.getElementsByTagName('audio');audio.play();`

Comment: Lo he intentado pero me dice que audio.play no es una funcion...

Comment: Prueba a hacer un `console.log(audio)` a ver si te devuelve el elemento audio del html

Answer (score 3):

Ya encontré el problema, estás usando `.getElementsByTagName()`, esto crea una lista con todos los elementos de tipo audio. Si quieres utilizar el método `play()` lo debes hacer en el elemento que te interesa al interno de esa lista y no sobre la lista `audio`.

Aquí te dejo algunas soluciones...

### Usar `.getElementById()`

```
<audio id="audio">...</audio>

<script>
    var audio = getElementById("audio");
    audio.play();
</script>
```

### Usar `.getElementsByTag()`

```
<audio>...</audio>

<script>
    var audio = getElementsByTag("audio");
    for (let i=0; i<audio.length; i++){
        audio[i].play();
    };
</script>
```

> PD: Si colocas el script justo antes de cerrar el tag `</body>` en lugar de hacerlo en el `</header>` no será necesario que controles que los elementos de la página se hayan cargado antes de inicializar la variable `audio`.

Comment: Si, esta vez me funciona, pero me dice que el usuario no ha interactuado con la página. No sé si me funcionará cuando lo pase a APK. De todas formas muchisimas gracias, de verdad.

Comment: Vale, lo he probado y sigue sin sonar en la aplicación. De verdad que no sé porqué no suena...

Comment: Ahí no se ayudarte, nunca he usado apk. Desarrollo aplicaciones web con frameworks de Python.